# Bluetooth LE не обнаруживает устройства

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, bluetooth

Делаю попытку обнаружения устройств с помощью [Bluetooth LE](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/master/README.md), сделал как написано в этой библиотеке для Xamarin, однако обнаруженных устройств 0

Необходимые манифесты в андроиде включил. Увеличил время для сканирования до 30 секунд, но ничего нет. На устройствах Bluetooth включен, версии 4.0

Устройство Asus_Z00ED (Android 6.0 - API 23). Проект создан с целевым на Android 8.1. Пытался переключать в манифесте целевые версии Android (8.0,9.0), однако обнаружения также нет

Какие ещё могут быть причины отсутствия обнаружения?

```
public class Page6 : ContentPage
    {
        IBluetoothLE ble;
        IAdapter adapter;
        ObservableCollection<IDevice> deviceList;
        Label label;

        public Page6()
        {
            ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            deviceList = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();

            label = new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" };
            var buttonList = new Button() { Text = "Devices List" };
            buttonList.Clicked += ButtonList_Clicked;

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    label,
                    buttonList,
                }
            };
        }

        private async void ButtonList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            deviceList.Clear();
            adapter.ScanTimeout = 30000;
            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
            {
                deviceList.Add(a.Device);
            };

            await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(); // сканирование

            label.Text = deviceList.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

[image: Манифест]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такой ответ, необходимо убрать из манифеста (AndroidManifest.xml) целевую платформу sdk и тогда сканнер успешно работает
В манифесте тогда это выглядит так:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```